# echo: "Why need to use \\ instead of \ to cancel the / character?"

Tags: shell, echo

```
~/Desktop $ echo */*
unix/junk unix/save unix/xyxxy
```

I would like to cancel the slash so the shell no longer prints the files of the directories. I've found out that

```
~/Desktop $ echo *\/*
unix/junk unix/save unix/xyxxy
```

doesn't work
,while

```
~/Desktop $ echo *\\/*
*\/*
```

does the job.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you're trying to cancel here is not the special behavior of the `\` character, but rather, the special behavior of the two `*` characters!

Me, I would use

```
echo '*/*'
```

or

```
echo "*/*"
```

Or, if you wanted to use `\`, the best way to do it would be

```
echo \*/\*
```

Actually, since there are almost certainly no files or directories named "*", you would usually be able to get away with just

```
echo \*/*
```

or

```
echo */\*
```

When you wrote

```
echo *\\/*
```

you were asking to see all the names of all the files in any subdirectory where the subdirectory name ended in a `\`.  There probably aren't any of those, but if you want to, to see what's going on, try invoking

```
mkdir x\\
touch x\\/y
touch x\\/z
```

and then do your

```
echo *\\/*
```

again.  You should see `x\/y x\/z`!

Comment: Which do you think is the best practice of the above? using ' ' or \ and why?

Comment: @Molnia: In general, I prefer to use `""` most of the time, especially if I might want to expand shell variables inside.  I use `''` if I definitely don't want to expand shell variables inside, or if I'm nesting `''` and `""` in some complicated situation.  I usually stay away from \ if I can, because more than a couple of them get confusing and hard to read real fast.

Answer (score 0):

A single backslash is used for special sequences like for instance `\n` . So to insert a real - escaping - backslash, you have to write `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to print the folders within your Desktop then use `echo */`

`echo *\\/*` will print anything withing a folder that ends with `\`
while `echo *\/*` will print anything withing any folder as the backslash (`\`) is not scaped

Answer (score -1):

I didn't make myself clear with the earlier answer. What's happening with the last command

```
~/Desktop $ echo *\\/*
*\/*
```

is basically `\` is escaping the next `\` and `*\/*` is just getting printed like any other ordinary string like it happens with `*something` or any other string `abc`